# Introduction to Hardy spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, harmonic-analysis

What text would you recommend for a (not too long) introduction to Hardy spaces? I am specially interested in real Hardy spaces but I also want to learn about complex ones.

I'm a graduate student with some background in harmonic, complex and functional analysis.

Comment: Something like a single chapter of a book would be nice :)

Comment: Barry Simon's harmonic analysis (third volume of "a comprehensive introduction to analysis") has a chapter on $H^p$ spaces.

Comment: I've taken a look at the table of contents and it looks very dense. Do you know of any lighter introduction?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider book titled " An introduction to operators on the Hardy Hilbert Space " by Avendano and Rosenthal.